# Find eigenvalues for $f(A) = A^t$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f(A)=A^t$ be a linear transformation. Prove that its eigenvalues are $-1$ and $1$.

My try:

$f^2(A) = A$ So, $\forall A,f^2(A)=1 \cdot A$ . That means that $1$ is a solution of $P_A(x)$, so its also a solution of $P_{A^t}(x) \implies $ $1$ is an eigenvalue of $f$. I don't know what to do abut $-1$.

Comment: If the dimension is large enough ($>1$), take an antisymmetric matrix. That will show that $-1$ is an eigenvalue. If the dimension is $1$, then $-1$ is not an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, any eigenvalue of $f$ is necessarily a square root of $1$, so either $1$ or $-1$. To check that these are both actually represented, you should give a matrix $A$ with $A^T=A$ and another matrix $B$ with $B^T=-B$. (Some assumptions you haven't given us are required to ensure $B$ exists, but $A$ always exists (consider for instance $A=I$)).

Comment: $B$ will not exist for $1\times 1$ matrices (and characteristic $\ne 2$) though

Answer (score 1):

minimal polynomial of f divides x^2-1, and hence -1 and 1 are the only possible eigenvalues of f and it is indeed the case. Take A to be symmetric matrix for 1 and Skew symmetric for -1.

Answer (score 1):

Every $A$ may be written as
$$
            A = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)+\frac{1}{2}(A-A^t),
$$
and
$$
          f(A) = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)-\frac{1}{2}(A-A^t).
$$
So $A$ has only $\pm 1$ as possible eigenvalues. Symmetric matrices are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $+1$; anti-symmetric matrices are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $-1$. There are no other eigenvalues because $f^2=I$.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there as $f^2(A)=A$ is just $(f^2-I)(A)=0$ corresponding multiple of minimal polynomial will be
$(x^2-1)$ which clearly implies that
 $(x+1)(x-1)=0$ and hence the result.

Comment: This show that the minimal polynomial divides $(x+1)(x-1)$, but how do you conclude that the minimal polynomial must be equal to $(x+1)(x-1)$?

Comment: I don't quite understand how $(f^2-I)(A)=0$ implies that the minimal polynomial divides $(x+1)(x-1)$.

Comment: @AlexMatt The first equation implies that $f$ satisfies $x^2-1=0$.

Comment: I still don't understand why. There must be something, in theory, I'm not familiar with.

Comment: By definition of minimal polynomial it is the polynomial of least degree which vanish the transformation @AlexMatt

Comment: @clark i have edited , it will surely be divisor

Comment: @AlexMatt Let $p(x)=(x+1)(x-1)$, then $p(I)=0$ however the minimal polynomial of the identity matrix is $x-1$ not $(x+1)(x-1)$, am I missing something?

Comment: @clark you are surely right but here in this case it's not possible otherwise transformation will be identity

Comment: This transformation is indeed the identity in dimension $1$.

Comment: @orole I agree with you but OP has not mentioned about the dimension I am assuming it to be greater than 1 other wise question will be very trivial